# Javascript not Pulling values from Form

Tags: javascript, html

When trying to value a URL based on values from a from it keeps returning null values, and throwing off the build of the URL.

I validated the ids match and are unique, but I am new to HTML/JavaScript so I am blind to what I am missing.

```js
function displayLink() {
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = URL;
}

var site = document.getElementById("site").value;
var prodtest1 = document.getElementById("test").value == "True" ? "-test.com/" : "-prod.com/";
var prodtest2 = document.getElementById("normal").value == "True" ? "test/" : "prod/";
var isBasic = document.getElementById("basic").value == "True" ? "AuthMethod=normal" : "html/public/";
var isHtml5 = document.getElementById("html").value == "True" ? "login.aspx" : "default.aspx";

var URL = Href = "https://" + site + prodtest1 + prodtest2 + isBasic + isHtml5;
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- Start Inputs -->
  <Form class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="site" id="site">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test">
    <label for="test">TEST</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="normal">
    <Label for="normal">normal</Label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="html">
    <label for="html">html</label>
  </Form>
  <button type="Button" onclick='displayLink()'>Generate Link</button>
  <!-- Inputs End -->
</div>
<!-- Display URL Result -->
<div id="URL">
  <br>
  <a id=Link HREF="Link">
</div>
```

Comment: "I validated the ids match" — Not very well. You have no id `basic` or `link` (although you do have `Link`).

Comment: @Andy — That's convention, but not a requirement of HTML which defines element and attribute names as case insensitive.

Comment: You can use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to check that there are no errors in the console (there are, at least in the code you have provided).

Comment: you are missing double-quotes in your `<a>`. It should be `<a id="Link" href="Link">`

Comment: I needed to change the IDs before posting, so it might not match here, but I've reviewed the actual copy and had someone else review it as well. Thanks for the information about the <a>

Comment: @YvesHendseth — They aren't missing. They are optional.

Comment: @StevenB1 — You need to provide a [mcve] that reflects your actual problem. Not one you've edited to demonstrate a different problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has some things wrong with it that I noticed:

- There's no element with an id of "basic"
- You don't have "Link" in quotes in your link at the bottom, you need to put these types of things in quotes
- Your variable naming isn't consistent, that might be something to decide on so that your code is a bit more readable.
- Because the URL is generated outside of the onClick() function, clicking the button multiple times with, say, different checkboxes activated or a different site entered into the input would have no effect.
- Even though the browser will usually let you get away with writing your elements like `<input type="checkbox" id="html">`, you should really have a closing / at the end of your elements. I.e. `<input type="checkbox" id="html" />` This is the syntax for a "self-closing" HTML element, you'll want to add that slash to the end.
- You'll have a better time checking if an input box is checked by just doing `document.getElementById("element").checked`

Have patience with yourself and just make sure you pay attention to these things when you write code. If you "fixed" all of these things (Notice "fixed" is in quotes because there are many correct ways of writing this code) it would look like this:

Html:

```
<div> 
<!-- Start Inputs -->
  <Form class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="site" id="site" /><br>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
    <label for="test">TEST</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="normal" />
    <label for="normal">normal</label>
    
    <label for="html">html</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="html" />
  </Form>
  <button type="Button" onclick='displayLink()'>Generate Link</button>
  <!-- Inputs End -->
  </div>
<!-- Display URL Result -->
<div id="URL">
  <br>
  <a id="link" HREF="" /> <!-- You don't need HREF="" here, but I left it to make it clear it started out as a blank string. -->
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayLink() {
    
  var siteInput = document.getElementById("site").value;
  var prodTest1 = document.getElementById("test").checked ? "-test.com/" : "-prod.com/";
  var prodTest2 = document.getElementById("normal").checked ? "test/" : "prod/";
// These is no element in your code with an ID of "basic" so this variable has been omitted. 
  var isHtml5 = document.getElementById("html").checked ? "login.aspx" : "default.aspx";
  
  var URL = "https://" + siteInput + prodTest1 + prodTest2 + isHtml5;
  console.log(URL)
  var linkElement = document.getElementById("link");
  linkElement.innerHTML = URL;
  linkElement.href = URL;
}
```

Comment: *There's no element with an id of "basic"* — The OP has already said that is a mistake that appears only in the question

Comment: *You don't have "Link" in quotes in your link at the bottom, you need to put these types of things in quotes* — That's wrong. Quotes around attribute values are optional (unless the value contains certain characters, which `Link` does not)

Comment: *Your variable naming isn't consistent, that might be something to decide on so that your code is a bit more readable.* — I don't see what this has to do with the problem.

Comment: *Because the URL is generated outside of the onClick() function, clicking the button multiple times with, say, different checkboxes activated or a different site entered into the input would have no effect.* — While true, it won't affect the "null values" the question is asking about. The only `null`s I can see are the ones returned by `getElementById` that the OP denies exist in their real code.

Comment: *Even though the browser will usually let you get away with writing your elements like `<input type="checkbox" id="html">`, you should really have a closing / at the end of your elements. I.e. `<input type="checkbox" id="html" />` This is the syntax for a "self-closing" HTML element, you'll want to add that slash to the end.* — Oh goodness no. XHTML is dead. That syntax hangover is pointless.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for spamming comments at me. Pointing out that there is no element with an ID of basic is pertinent because it makes it clear he needs to re-read his code more carefully before posting questions about it on forums. OP consistently uses quotes around attributes in other parts of his code, not doing it one time in a random place is just *bad* formatting, there's no way around that. Variable naming is in the same vein, camel casing sometimes and then not is just *bad* formatting.

Comment: @Quentin My statement about the button not generating new links when clicked multiple times is true, I attempted to show him a better way of doing this rather than going into the specifics of the nulls. Self closing HTML tags are, from what I have seen, almost always written with a /> at the end. XHTML is not dead, it simply matters who you're talking to/where you work. You really do not need to be this nit picky about a question and you know it, these comments are not helpful towards the OP.

Comment: @Shades - Thanks for your help in this. I also appreciate your explaining this without getting too technical. I'm still learning, so I appreciate you not being toxic and explaining patiently and clearly.

Comment: @StevenB1 Of course! Stack overflow has a hit-or-miss community much of the time, and people can be quite impatient. Learning to ask questions on forums is a skill in it of itself that requires practice, just make sure you're thoroughly reading your code and attempt to google your question before posting it and you will generally be well-received.

Answer (score -1):

For the checkbox type of input, the **checked** attribute will return a boolean value of true or false for you to use with your ternary conditions.

```
var prodtest1 = document.getElementById("test").checked ? "-test.com/" : "-prod.com/";
```

More information is available in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked)